# I have 3 stages to build in jenkins using pipeline code (Scripted0

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 3 stages(a,b,c) to run on jenkins using pipeline code(scripted), I 
need to run stage a,b in parallel and run c after a is success (I am 
doing this using pipeline code) but in blue ocean it showing only task 
name but I wanna see stage names(in this case I have only 2 tasks with 3 
stages and stage a and c are in one task). can someone help how can view 
all three stages according to this situation.

```
def stages = [failFast: false]
  def testList = ["a", "b", "c"]

  def tasks = [:]
  tasks["a-and-c"] = {
    stage ("a"){ 
      ansiColor('xterm') {
        sh " ls -lart; sleep 30 "
      }
      if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS') {
          stage("c") {
            ansiColor('xterm') {
              sh " ls -lart "
            }
          }
      } else {
          sh 'exit'
      }
       }
     }  
  tasks["c"] = {
    stage ("c"){    
      ansiColor('xterm') {
          sh " ls -lart; sleep 20"
      }
    }
}

parallel tasks
```

I am expecting to have a separate view in blueocean for all three stages, 
right now I am getting a-and-c and b parallel but I looking for a,b as 
parallel and c after a is success. Thank you in advance.
[image]